# Why I'm I getting 'Cannot connect to docker daemon' error while installing the Fabric Samples and binaries for HyperLedgerFabric?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I'm following steps from [hlf documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/install.html)

When I'm trying to install the Fabric Samples and binaries, I'm getting the following error:
[image: error]

I checked docker daemon and its running, container I chose is **Kubernetes**:
[image: Docker is running]

What can I do to resolve this? Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might have to do with pulling Linux images on a Windows machine. Docker Desktop, right?

Comment: Yes. I tried pulling trial Hello World image, it was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving elevated access.

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

You can read more at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1825